# reuse SSL session on C client/server application

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am writing a client/server application that we'll use SSL communication. I have a hard time trying to figure out why external caching isn't working. I don't want to use internal caching because I want to store the session in a database. Although I've registered a callabck for `SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb` and `SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb, SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb`won't get called on the server side and at every connection a new SSL_SESSION it's created. It almost seems like the client doesn't send at handshake a session_id but I'm not sure and have no ideea how to test this. On the client side I am attaching the session to the SSL connection with SSL_set_session and I'm using openSSL 0.9.8 on Ubuntu.

```
//for server side
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_SERVER | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_AUTO_CLEAR );

//for client side
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_CLIENT | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_AUTO_CLEAR );
```

Basically the flow of both the client and the server looks like this. For clarity I've removed the error handling. In case of success the application will pass through all of them.

```
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();

ctx = SSL_CTX_new( SSLv23_method() );

SSL_CTX_set_info_callback(ctx, &apps_ssl_info_callback );
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations( ctx,calist_file, calist_path );
SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,certfile,SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx,password_cb);
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ctx, password );
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx,keyfile,SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) );
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx,password_cb);
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ctx, password );
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx,keyfile,SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx);
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, verify_callback);
SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list( ctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file( calist_file ) );
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx,2);
```

/*my routines that handle fetching the DH params and creating RSA temp key and randomness*/

```
RAND_load_file( random, SIZE );
load_dh_params(ctx,DHFILE); 
generate_eph_rsa_key(ctx);

SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context(ctx,(void*)&s_server_session_id_context,sizeof (s_server_session_id_context) );
mydata_index = SSL_get_ex_new_index(0, "mydata index", NULL, NULL, NULL);

SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, (ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_SERVER | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL |  SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_AUTO_CLEAR );
SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb(ctx, get_session_cb);
SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb(ctx, new_session_cb );
SSL_CTX_sess_set_remove_cb(ctx, remove_session_cb );
```

What I want is when a client connects the get_session_cb should be called and there I will select the session id based some criterias( in the future the session id will have some sort of meaning( host id) not just random number but this part it's not implemented right now). If there is no session that matches my criteria than the application will make one via new_session_cb. The sever should have the same behaviour, first will try to find the session in its pool of sessions and if the finding was unsuccesfull only then to make a new one.

I am not sure if what I want for the client is really possible. So that's way I've even tried just to get one session and have it set manually via SSL_set_session( ssl, session ).

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

It's very hard to say without seeing all the other OpenSSL calls in your code, we'd really need a self-contained sample exhibiting the problem.  That being said, this sounds like it could be trouble with the [RFC 5077](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077) server-stateless session resumption using the session ticket extension.  Turning it off avoided some of the problems I experienced with external sessions:

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(sslctx, SSL_OP_NO_TICKET);
```

However, if you want to go down the server-stateless session resumption road, it would be totally expected that on the server side there is no call into your external session cache -- that's the exactly point of session resumption without server-state.

Comment: (OpenSSL 1.1.1) I had a situation where after the successful `BIO_do_handshake` call on the server side, I could not get a valid session ID (on the server side) - it returned length 0 (also, the session ID related callbacks weren't called) - which I suppose is the point of "*server-stateless*" after all. The client (third party application), however, was still able to connect later with a valid session ID in its ClientHello message. Adding `SSL_CTX_set_options(sslctx, SSL_OP_NO_TICKET)` "fixed" this for me - the server now had a valid session ID after the handshake.